# Can I use the same url for a webhook from more than one Telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have a webhook configured and working from one of my Telegram bots.  I would now like to use the **same** URL for the webhook from a second Telegram bot but it isn't working for me.

Can anyone shed light on this for me please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use the same url for multiple bot, you can use the same base url for multiple bot (same domain name).

For example you have the domain `example.com` you could set

- `example.com/bot1`
- `example.com/bot2`

etc...

The scheme of the url is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a URL for each BOT and refactor the function that it execute. For example:

OlderVersion

```
app.post("/telegram/webhook", function (req, res) {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = a * b;
}

app.post("/telegram/webhook2", function (req, res) {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var c = a * b;
}
```

New Version

```
app.post("/telegram/webhook", function (req, res) {
    multiply();
}

app.post("/telegram/webhook2", function (req, res) {
    multiply();
}

function multiply(){
   var a = 1;
   var b = 2;
   var c = a * b;
}
```